# How to control Holoviews y-tick format?

Tags: python, scientific-notation, holoviews

I am trying to gain control of the Holoviews Curve (though this should work for any other plotting element) and set the y-tick labels to be in scientific notations.

In MatPlotLib I would do this with `ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))`.

Currently I have this:

[image: Current Holoview y-ticks]

But would like the Y axis numbers to be in scientific notations instead of the long decimal numbers currently shown on the Y axis.

Is there anyway to do this and what is it?

Comment: Can you format the numbers yourself and use the resulting strings as the labels?

Answer (score 3):

HoloViews let's you supply a tick formatter directly on a Dimension, so you can do something like this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
yfmt = ScalarFormatter()
yfmt.set_powerlimits((0,0))
yfmt.set_scientific(True)
hv.Curve(np.random.rand(10), vdims=[hv.Dimension('y', value_format=yfmt)])
```

If you ever find options that you can't control directly you can always attach hooks on your Element, which will give you direct control over the plotting object, e.g.:

```
def sciticks(plot, element):
    plot.handles['axis'].ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))

hv.Curve(np.random.rand(10,2))(plot=dict(final_hooks=[sciticks]))
```

The `plot` argument to the callback function is the HoloViews plotting class, which will let you access various plotting objects on its `handles` attribute. The handles contain various important plot objects, for example the `'axis'` keyword corresponds to the matplotlib `Axes` object, but among other things you can also access and modify the Figure using `'fig'` and the `Artist` using `'artist'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using 'matplotlib' as backend for holoviews, you should try the `ScalarFormatter`  by simply calling the `yformatter` argument in `.opts`.

Try this:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
yfmt = ScalarFormatter()
yfmt.set_powerlimits((0,0))
yfmt.set_scientific(True)

your_fig.opts(yformatter=yfmt)
```